# Passing params to Salesforce Screen Flow in Slack

Tags: screen-flow, slack, slack-salesforce-app

I am trying to show a Salesforce Screen Flow in Slack with the new native Salesforce-Slack integration.
I enabled my screen flow for Slack but I when I do this, I can no longer pass any input variable from the flow that triggers this screen flow, so although I can see my screen flow inside Slack, I cannot use it to update any specific record or create any record that references someone existing record.
What is the right way to pass an input param into a Slack-enabled screen flow?

Answer (score 1):

Starting winter 23 you should be able to pass in parameters from your Flows to the Screen flows for Slack. You can find more information on this by reading the release [notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_extend_slack_invocable_action.htm&type=5&release=240).